# Creating independent Module in Magnolia 5.3

Tags: module, content-management-system, magnolia

I created custom Module with Magnolia Archetype from this link : [Module QuickStart](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Module+QuickStart)
But directly in my workspace, I mean without creating webApp Project.
So when I want to use on my module that is integrated in webApp project I can't find resources like component.ftl.

Please help me if there is useful tutorial for creating a custom independent module and thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You want to use your module in some other webapp than one you created it in, or you want in your newly created module component from some other module you have in the webapp? Some example of what you are trying to achieve might help.

Comment: the first one : I want to use my Module in some other webapp than I created in for example I have two Magnolia Project, I create my module in the first one but now I want to use it in the second like the module proposed by Magnolia (example : Rest...)

Comment: If I understood the question properly, then you may import it via maven by adding the dependency of the module to the webapps pom.

Answer (score 0):

by CMD go to your workspace with the command cd: for example

```
cd users/workspace
```

Now in your workspace run this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

This command creates your module, there is 5 options, follow the instructions to create your best module.